# Pythonic way to update the value of a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I am given a task to update MongoDB document timestamp-type field. Because of different kinds of field name, I have to check field name many times. This code works and does exactly what I want to, but it is inelegant. Is there has any pythonic way?

```
'''

--------------- user ---------------
_id              |   ObjectId
user_id          |   int
name             |   str
last_login_time  |   int

--------------------- post ---------------------
_id                    |   ObjectId
post_id                |   int
title                  |   str
content                |   str
lastest_comment_time   |   int

'''


import time
from database import mongo_client

def update_time_field(row):
    if "last_login_time" in row: row["last_login_time"] = time.time()
    if "lastest_comment_time" in row: row["lastest_comment_time"] = time.time()
    
    return row

if __name__=="__main__":
    # mongo_client is a instance of MongoClient
    user_info = mongo_client.user.find_one({"user_id": 1})
    user_info = update_time_field(user_info)
    mongo_client.user.replace_one({"user_id": 1}, user_info)

    post_info = mongo_client.post.find_one({"post_id": 277})
    post_info = update_time_field(post_info)
    mongo_client.post.replace_one({"post_id": 277}, post_info)
```

All comments and suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Missing Review Context: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks for comment. I have edited this question.

Comment: Is the `if in` check really necessary? Why would a field be missing, and if it is missing, wouldn't you want to add it?

Comment: @Reinderien The collections have difference timestamp field name, so the `if in` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's mostly fine, but I would write it as:

```
def update_time(row) -> None:
    fields = ("last_login_time", "latest_comment_time")
    timestamp = time.time()
    for f in fields:
        if f in row:
            row[f] = timestamp
```

There are two differences here:

1. I'm guessing you don't want different timestamps if the row contains both fields.
2. You're mutating the row inside the function, so you don't need to return it.

Note if the row can contain exactly one field, and you have many different fields, you can break after updating the row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the fact, that the function `update_time_field()` has a side effect, i.e. modifies the given object, and also returns it, which kind of makes it pretend to be a pure function.

I suggest using either a function with side-effects, returning `None` as suggested by @hahdawg or preferably a pure function.

```py
from time import time
from typing import Any

...

TIME_FIELDS = {'last_login_time', 'latest_comment_time'}


def update_timestamps(row: dict[str, Any], timestamp: time) -> dict[str, Any]:
    """Return a new row with updated time stamps."""

    return {
        key: timestamp if key in TIME_FIELDS else value
        for key, value in row.items()
    }

...

user_info = update_timestamps(user_info, time())
...
```